# Cython - "TypeError: expected bytes, str found"

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to speed up my **"for loop"** that contains 7 more "for loops" inside. The idea is that you can run the function like this `breaker("akzH6Fs0")` and it will break the password that you wrote in the quotes. Sadly I get an error as in title. I tried to surf but nothing helps.

I'm using python 3.8.2 version.

Here's the code:

```
import time

cpdef breaker(char *a):
       strings = list("abcčćdđefghijklmnoprsštuvzžqwxy1234567890ABCČĆDĐEFGHIJKLMNOPRSŠTUVZŽQWXY")
       cdef char string1
       cdef char string2
       cdef char string3
       cdef char string4
       cdef char string5
       cdef char string6
       cdef char string7
       cdef char string8
       for string1 in strings:
              for string2 in strings:
                     for string3 in strings:
                            for string4 in strings:
                                   for string5 in strings:
                                          for string6 in strings:
                                                 for string7 in strings:
                                                        for string8 in strings:
                                                               if a == string1 + string2 + string3 + string4 + string5 + string6 + string7 + string8:
                                                                      password = string1 + string2 + string3 + string4 + string5 + string6 + string7 + string8
                                                                      time.sleep(1)
                                                                      print("your password is", password)
                                                                      time.sleep(10)
                                                                      quit()

                                                               print(string1 + string2 + string3 + string4 + string5 + string6 + string7 + string8)
```

This is the whole traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\korisnik\Desktop\edps_tests\testing.py", line 3, in <module>
    edps_test.breaker("password")
  File "edps_test.pyx", line 3, in edps_test.breaker
    cpdef breaker(char *a):
TypeError: expected bytes, str found
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\korisnik\Desktop\edps_tests\testing.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\korisnik\Desktop\edps_tests]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;D:\webdrivers;C:\Users\korisnik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\korisnik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\korisnik\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\korisnik\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\bin;]
```

Solution will be great but I will really appreciate just an explanation of the error and my mistake. I am begginer in cython by the way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The fundamental problem is you are trying to use a brute-force search.

Comment: Please include the complete traceback.

Comment: Anyway, `cdef char` expects bytes, not str AFAIKT

Comment: @robinsax, did it.

Answer (score 0):

As your traceback points out, `char*` can't handle being passed a `str`. This is because in Python 3.* `str` is actually a unicode string container.

The safe way to accept string arguments from the interpreter is by declaring them as the `str` type. For example:

```py
cpdef breaker(str a):
    # etc...
```

See https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html#accepting-strings-from-python-code for more info.

*Important note*: As far as I can tell this function doesn't actually seem to be achieving anything. It will (very slowly) print the input string so long as it contains only characters in your defined string list. What are you trying to accomplish?